# A single word for "merely reporting a fact"?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a single word to express the idea "merely reporting a fact" in a context such as "I am not saying this complacently but *X*" where *X* is the required word representing "merely reporting a fact". Alternatively, *X* can also be a word simply for "reporting a fact".

Comment: Though it doesn't mean "reporting a fact", *factually* can be used in the place of X.

Comment: Oh much appreciated. I assume "can be used .." is meant with respect to the given context?

Comment: Yes. I meant so. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic way of saying this in English would not be to use a single word. The most natural way to say this, in English, would be something like:

> I'm not trying to make trouble; I'm just telling you the facts.

or

> ..I'm just telling you what I saw.

or something along those lines.

If you want a single word, the closest I can come up with is **objectively.**  This has the meaning you want, but if you use it in this context, it will sound somewhat arrogant or obnoxious. It would be better to soften it:

> I'm not saying this to make trouble; I'm just trying to be objective.

Also: the phrase

> I'm not saying this complacently

itself sounds a bit awkward. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to say, but I suspect there's a better way to say it.